# `IDs:=paste(AgentID)` doesn't contain all `AgentID`s

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(Time = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2), State = c(56L, 81L, 126L, 161L, 120L, 138L, 71L, 
133L, 6L, 171L, 42L, 64L, 28L, 76L, 56L, 117L, 47L, 69L, 65L, 
105L, 175L, 151L, 0L, 91L, 150L, 157L, 172L, 69L, 132L, 39L, 
152L, 107L, 142L, 174L, 187L, 84L, 58L, 73L, 198L, 5L, 43L, 189L, 
34L, 177L, 119L, 69L, 152L, 155L, 44L, 59L, 20L, 120L, 1L, 173L, 
190L, 121L, 118L, 168L, 80L, 45L, 26L, 15L, 190L, 25L, 7L, 146L, 
177L, 41L, 28L, 190L, 64L, 76L, 194L, 13L, 172L, 120L, 132L, 
160L, 58L, 12L), AgentID = 1:80), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

What I want to do is to detect which of the `AgentID`s have the same `State`, and store them as `collidedIDs`, something like

```
a[, collidedIDs:=paste(AgentID), by=.(State)]
```

However, the above code results in a new column only containing the exact copy of `AgentID` even though, for instance, there are 3 agents at `State=190`, their `collidedIDs` only contain their own `AgentID`.

I can't understand why my code doesn't work.

**Question**
Why does my code not work? How can I fix it?

Comment: Compare `paste(c("a", "b"))` and `paste(c("a", "b"), collapse = "")`.

Comment: @Roland so in the former case, it return 2 elements? I can't understand the type of the output in the first case

Comment: `paste(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"))`

Comment: Btw., your desired output is not useful for data analysis. I'd only do that for reporting purposes.

Comment: @Roland I know but I couldn't find a direct way of creating a column `IDs` which contains the ID of the collided agent (if there is any). The issue is even more complicated since there could be a case where more than one agent collides at the same time.

Comment: @Roland Because at the same time I don't want `IDs` to contain the `AgentID` itself (an agent can't collide with itself)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that keeping the `AgentID` values separate is useful, which points to using list-columns. Typically, a column is just a vector, and if you see commas in it then it is a *string*; using a list-column the column is not a vector.

For demonstration, a "normal" vector-based frame/`data.table`:

```r
str(DT)
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    80 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Time   : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ State  : int  56 81 126 161 120 138 71 133 6 171 ...
#  $ AgentID: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

A reduced `data.table` with a list-column:

```r
str(DT[, .(collidedIDs = list(AgentID)), by = .(State)][1:4,])
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ State      : int  56 81 126 161
#  $ collidedIDs:List of 4
#   ..$ : int  1 15
#   ..$ : int 2
#   ..$ : int 3
#   ..$ : int 4
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

A suggestion solution for you is

```r
DT[, .(collidedIDs = list(AgentID)), by = .(State)]
#     State collidedIDs
#     <int>      <list>
#  1:    56        1,15
#  2:    81           2
#  3:   126           3
#  4:   161           4
#  5:   120     5,52,76
### ..truncated..
```